# Start program on PC using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want to create arduino sketch that start program on my computer (i.e., browser) when I push button on Arduino itself.

Is it possible to make it using Arduino uno? I already know how to make a serial connection between PC and Arduino and use Processing software, but as I know, Processing cannot interact with another programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing is just Java.  If Java can do it Processing can do it.

And Java can do it.

Just ask Google about the Java `ProcessBuilder` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the Arduino look like a keyboard/mouse to the PC and then reproduce some key combo that will perform the action you want.
See reference [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard).